# the default metric for feature importance for CatBoost

Tags: catboost

I am using both CatBoost classification and regression model and having hard time to figure out what metrics are being used by feature importance.

According to the CatBoost Doc, it is PredictionValuesChange for non-ranking metrics and LossFunctionChange for ranking metrics.

I don't understand what ranking and non-ranking means here. You can rank the probability generated by any models. 
In what case, ranking/non-ranking metrics are used?

Answer (score 0):

Ranking is all the metrics that falls under the following categories:
[catboost ranking metrics](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/loss-functions-ranking.html)

the rest would be considered non-ranking and use PredictionValuesChange for the feature importance.